# Do Shia read darood E Ibrahim in tasshahud?

Tags: salat, shiism

Sunnis recite darood E Ibrahim in final tasshahud of every prayer.

**Do Shia also recite darood E ibrahim? And is it different from Sunnis?**

Searching google gives link to Shia chat and topic doesn't mention darood E Ibrahim being recited in prayer.

Sunni darud-e-Ibrahim: [www.google.co.in/amp/s/islamgreatreligion.wordpress.com](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/islamgreatreligion.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/durood-e-ibrahim/amp/)

Comment: Shouldn't you be more specific as to which sub-sect of the Shias are you referring to? I understand there are some differences of opinion among them.

Answer (score 2):

Shia Muslims  do not recite Durood-e-Ibrahim in tashahud. But they recite a complete salawaat for the Prophet and his family.

> Allahumma salli'ala Muhammad wa al-e-Muhammad.

The Prophet commanded the believers  to not only send prayers upon himself but include his family as well. He said: "Do not send an amputated prayer". The companions asked,'What is an amputated prayer?' He said, "When you say 'Allahumma, salli 'ala Muhammad" and stop. Rather, you should say, "Allahumma, salli 'ala Muhammad wa al-e-Muhammad."

```
> Yanabi' al-Muwaddah, Vo.2, p.59; Ibn Hajar, al-Sawa'iq al-Muhriqah, ch.11, sec.1
```

Durood-e-Ibrahim is another indication, that the inclusion of the family of the Prophet in the prayer is important.

The link given in the question shows the prayer in beautiful Arabic calligraphy; however, the translation of it is misleading, as *al-e-Muhammad* and *al-e-Ibrahim* are translated as followers and not family / progeny which brings a significant difference to the meaning.

Comment: Your mentioned hadith ("Do not send an amputated prayer") was de facto a interesting/informative hadith, Allah bless you.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know/researched, Shia Muslims don't recite it; but, instead, in Salam/Final-Tashahud of prayer, they recite the following Dhikr(s):

> السلام علیک ایها النبی و رحمه الله و برکاته /Meaning: Peace, mercy and blessings) of God be upon you prophet.
>
> السلام علینا و علی عباد الله الصالحین / Meaning: Peace be upon us (the ones who prayer) and all God’s righteous servants.
>
> السلام علیکم و رحمه الله و برکاته / Meaning: Peace, mercy and blessings of God be
> upon you all (Mo'menin).

**Note:** the last part -3th part- seems to be Wajib, but the 1st and the 2nd parts seem to be Mustahab (recommended) to recite.

**Conclusion:**

Shia Muslims don't read/recite that Dhikr (as you mentioned), and they use another Dhikr (Salam/Taslim) in the last part of the prayer based on reference(s). E.g., ref.:
["www.al-islam.org, How to Perform
the Daily Prayers" (Shia form)](https://www.al-islam.org/nutshell/files/prayers.pdf)

---

**Source:** [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa16180) and [madreseha.com](http://madreseha.com/forum/index.php/topic,5166.0.html)